# Scraping linked HTML webpages by looping the rvest::follow_link() function

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

How can I loop the `rvest::follow_link()` function to scrape linked webpages?

Use Case:

1. Identify all *Lego Movie* cast members
2. Follow all *Lego Movie* cast member links
3. Grab a table of each movie (+ year) for all cast members

The required selectors I need are below:

```
library(rvest)
lego_movie <- html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
lego_movie <- lego_movie %>%
  html_nodes(".itemprop , .character a") %>%
  html_text()

# follow cast links
(".itemprop .itemprop") 

# grab tables of all movies and dates for each cast member
(".year_column , b a")
```

Desired Output:

```
castMember       movie    year
Will Arnett      Lego     2017
Will Arnett      BoJack   2014
Will Arnett      Wander   2014
        ............
Elizabeth Banks  Moonbeam 2015
Elizabeth Banks  Wet Hot  2015
        ............
Alison Brie      Get Hard 2015
Alison Brie      GetaJob  2015
        .....etc.....
```

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like this could work.

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(data.table)
lego_movie <- read_html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
cast <- lego_movie %>%
    html_nodes("#titleCast .itemprop span") %>%
    html_text()
cast

s <- html_session("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")

cast_movies <- list()

for(i in cast[1:3]){
    actorpage <- s %>% follow_link(i) %>% read_html()
    cast_movies[[i]]$movies <-  actorpage %>% 
        html_nodes("b a") %>% html_text() %>% head(10)
    cast_movies[[i]]$years <- actorpage %>%
        html_nodes("#filmography .year_column") %>% html_text() %>% 
        head(10) %>% str_extract("[0-9]{4}")
    cast_movies[[i]]$name <- rep(i, length(cast_movies[[i]]$years))
}

cast_movies
as.data.frame(cast_movies[[1]])
rbindlist(cast_movies)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, so it may be wrong. I'd go through it step by step and verify that it's correct. I'm not sure about how to use follow_link in this context... but here's what I came up with...

```
library("rvest")
library("stringr")
lego_movie <- html("http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1490017/")
links <- lego_movie %>%
            html() %>%
            html_nodes(".itemprop , a") %>% xml_attr("href")
links[is.na(links)] <- ""

actors <- lego_movie %>%
  html() %>%
  html_nodes(".itemprop , a") %>%
html_text()

df <- data.frame(name=actors, link=links, stringsAsFactors=F)
df <- subset(df, substring(link, 2, 5)=="name")
df <- subset(df, name!="")
df$name <- gsub("\\n", "", df$name)
df$name <- str_trim(df$name)
df <- df[order(df$name),]
df <- subset(df, !duplicated(df$name))

get_movies <- function(name, link){
  url <- paste0("http://www.imdb.com", link)
  movies <- url %>%
    html() %>%
    html_nodes(".year_column , b a") %>%
    html_text()
  # take care of random date at top of some actors stuff...
  if(length(movies)%%2==1){movies <- movies[-1]}
  movies <- gsub("\\n", "", movies)
  movies <- str_trim(movies)
  df <- data.frame(date=movies[seq(1, length(movies), 2)], 
                   movie=movies[seq(2, length(movies), 2)],
                   stringsAsFactors=F)
  df <- cbind(name=rep(name, nrow(df)), df)
  return(df)
}

final_df <- data.frame()
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  final_df <- rbind(final_df, get_movies(df$name[i], df$link[i]))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this doesn't really answer the question. Based in the rvest documentation (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rvest/rvest.pdf) it seems like the follow_link() function should drastically reduce the code. But the doc examples aren't explicit enough to adapt to other cases...

Comment: I apoligize, will try harder next time.

Comment: I might be able to adapt the code for my use... but I hope we get to see how the follow_link function might be leveraged!