# web scraping with R, clicking on links

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am a beginner, I would like to scrape all the articles with the selected keyword from the page. I can scrape only the titles of articles displayed on a single page, a part of the description of articles and their links. I would not only like to scrape the search results, but also the content of each of the displayed links.

website: http://search.time.com/?site=time&q=bitcoin

```js
require(rvest)
url<- "http://search.time.com/?site=time&q=bitcoin"
webpage <- read_html(url)

title_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.content-title a')

title_data <- html_text(title_data_html)

description_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.content-snippet')
description_data <- html_text(description_data_html)

links = html_attr(title_data_html, name = "href")
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you're after is `follow_link()` from the `rvest` package.  Here is another SO post about this topic:

[Scraping linked HTML webpages by looping the rvest::follow_link() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28863775/scraping-linked-html-webpages-by-looping-the-rvestfollow-link-function)